# Double tap html element to fill screen width on a PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser

On mobile browsers, one could double tap on a certain region of site content and the page would automatically zoom in to that element to fit the entire width of the window. Is it possible to achieve this on a modern desktop browser such as Chrome or Firefox, in desktop Windows 7, without touch input?

I am not asking about the generic zoom using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, nor am I referring to CSS's zoom property. I have tried to use Windows 10's tablet mode, and yet a mouse input is still a mouse input.

Comment: This "feature" on mobile phones is something that is build into that browser. Not every browser on mobile phones have this feature either. That said, this is a software recommendation, something that is considered Off-Topic here on SuperUser. Please see the help center to learn about what kind of questions you can ask here.

Comment: I don't see a software request here. The answer *may* be "you need software X", but as-written the question isn't specifically requesting software.